# Facebook automatic feed post in page using javascript api

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to post a feed in facebook page? I have done in my wall post but i don't know how to do wall post in page using javascript api.
Actually, I want like[image: feed post in my facebook wall]

And I found the code from facebook api.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out this :

```
<body>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<p>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Group</a>
</p>
<p id='msg'></p>

<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "Yourappid", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
      FB.api('/Pageid/feed', 'post', 
              { 
                  // for the newer versions of the Facebook API you need to add the access token
                  access_token: 'page access token'
                  message     : "It's awesome ...",
                  link        : 'Link',
                  picture     : 'Imageurl',
                  name        : 'Featured of the Day',
                  to: 'Pageid',
                  from: 'Pageid',
                  description : 'Your description'
          }, 
          function(response) {

              if (!response || response.error) {
                  alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
              } else {
                  alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
              }
          });
  }

</script>
</body>
```

Put into your HTML body tag.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Search for the feed headline, with this text:

> You can create a link, post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the PAGE_ID/feed connection
>
> To impersonate the Page when posting to the wall (i.e. post as the Page, and not the current user), you must use a Page access_token with the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions, as described under Page Access Tokens above.